# External links won't open in Cordova web app - Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications

We have an existing web app which was running in an old version of Cordova. We had to update our Cordova version to 9.0.0. Unfortunately the current links in our web app aren't open externally in the system browser any more. The  platform is Android.

Currently the InAppBrowser is requested like:

```
function onDeviceReady() { 
[...]
       window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
[...]
```

We already installed and removed the InAppBrowser plugin and tried the following approaches in our existing web app to open the URL in the system browser e.g. Chrome:

```
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_system'); return false;">Test </a>

<a href="https://google.com" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_blank'); return false;">Test </a>

<a href="https://google.com" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;">Test</a>

<a href="https://google.com" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');">Test</a>

<a href="https://google.com" onclick="window.open('https://google.com', '_system'); return false;">Test</a>
```

I hope there is an solution to open links through an existing web-app to the system browser. We don't want to open the links in the existing app, this wouldn't be user-friendly. Furthermore we currently don't have the time to develop a native android app or change the behaviour of the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you looked in logcat? What are the symptoms?

Comment: What is your Content-Security-Policy ?

Comment: CSP shouldn't be the issue, in the config.xml 
 <access origin="*" /> is set. Logcat has no useful hints unfortunately

Comment: do you see an error in the console with chrome developer tools? did you try in JS after device ready 'cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');'

Comment: @JakeNeumann I did and it worked. Unfortunately the exact same request doesn't work if I make a request to an existing website in which the mentioned link is embedded.